# Is there a way to more concisely print the multiples of a specific number?

Tags: python

```
def first_three_multiples(num):
  print(num)
  print(num*2)
  print(num*3)
  return num*3

first_three_multiples(10)
first_three_multiples(0)
```

If I were to print let say the first 45 multiples of 3, is there a way to make this more concise? (Edited)

Comment: `print("\n".join(str(num * n) for n in range(1,46)))`

Comment: I suggest that you read [the Official Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and work through its exercises. It includes a section on loops, which are the direct answer to your question. It will also show you what other basic tools are available for writing robust programs in Python.

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where the utility of `for` loops is made very clear.

```
def print_first_multiples(num, multiples):
   for i in range(1, multiples+1):
       print(num*i)
   return num*multiples
```

The above script will print the first `multiples` multiples of `num`, starting with `1` (`num*1`), up to `multiples` (`num*multiples`).

For example, if you were to pass `print_first_multiples` the parameters `(10, 45)` it would print the first `45` multiples of `10`:

```
10
20
...
440
450
```

Since you seem unfamiliar with `for` loops (hence your question), I'll add a note on why I structured it how I did.

You may imagine, when you first want to design the `for` loop, that you would use something like

`for i in range(multiples)`

If you were to try this, you would notice that the first `print` of the above example would be `0`, rather than `10`, and the last output would be `440`, rather than `450`. This is because the `range()` function starts from `0`, and continues to one less than the value of it's input parameter (`45`), meaning it's range would be `(0, 44)`. Since we instead want the range to be `(1, 45)`, we shift the start point of `range` to `1`, and the end point to `multiples+1`, leaving us with `range(1, multiples+1)`.

This is important for when you loop through the indices of `lists`, as the indices of `lists` start at `0`, and continue to one less than the length of the list (`len(example_list)-1`), so `range(len(example_list))` would return all of the indices of `example_list`, whereas `range(1, len(example_list)+1)` would start at `1` (the second index of `example_list`) and continue to `len(example_list)`, which would be one larger than the last index of `example_list`.